# Fragment compatibility issues:

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am following the tutorial on the [android website](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) on how to have a button switch the fragment. Well I am receiving conflict between `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` and `android.app.Fragment`. So I tried changing all The fragments on the page to one or the other but it seams that both are needed for the process although this isn't possible.

To elaborate, the first thing it has you do is create a fragment manager like so:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
```

The problem I have down the line is that this line of code wants the `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` while the default generated one on a brand new activity is `android.app.Fragment`. I then tried switching the default generated one over and that gives me a different conflict. It would be helpful if someone could show me or link me to a tutorial where they properly present which fragment class to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using
`import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;`
you must use `getSupportFragmentManager();` instead of `getFragmentManager();`.

Source: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html

Comment: Looking into this as we speak and thanks would have never seen that.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the v4 for all related fragment actions.

In your case :

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
```

Comment: I am now getting this The method replace(int, android.app.Fragment) in the type FragmentTransaction is not applicable for the arguments (int, android.support.v4.app.Fragment)